# Can I write file in root directory android?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a question that I can write a file in root directory by this code?
when I test on emulator then it can write at path: /data/data/com.example.test/files/g.gc
but i donot know that i can write file on device, because i donot have any device to check it.

```
public static void saveFile(Context context, String content) {
    try {

        FileOutputStream fw = context.openFileOutput("g.gc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        fw.write( content);

        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot write to root because you do not have permission to. Your application must have an elevated UID level access to be able to write into the root directory.

If you're an app, don't bother.

Comment: but i see some application can write file to /data/data/packagename/files.

Comment: This is because that space is reserved for their application specifically they cannot write anything outside of their location in data/data/. Aside from the SDCARDwhich can be written by anything with the basic permission. That is how Context works between applications.